# Triggering ADO pipeline when branch is updated by other pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

### Background

On our Azure DevOps project we have a pipeline (call it "cascade merge pipeline") that, as the name suggests, starts a cascading merge of branches. I.e. when a pull request merges into a `release/*` branch, the pipeline is triggered and attempts to merge the target release branch into downstream release branches ending with `master`. This is handled with a PowerShell script and no YAML.

E.g. a developer completes a pull request into `release/1.1`. The cascade merge pipeline triggers and because other developers are simultaneously working on `release/1.2` it merges `release/1.1` into `release/1.2` and then merges `release/1.2` into `master`. So far so good.

### Problem

We have another pipeline that uploads our source code to Sigrid (for code quality/maintainability scoring) using their [CI tool](https://github.com/Software-Improvement-Group/sigridci/blob/main/docs/azure-devops.md). As a build validation step for all pull requests targeting a `release/*` branch this is run to produce feedback on the PR and without "publishing" the code to Sigrid's portal. However, we'd also like it to run whenever the `master` branch is updated which should publish the source code, such that Sigrid's baseline is up-to-date and such that the build validation step produces meaningful feedback that shows the developer a score for only the code they changed.

**The pipeline, however, never triggers after the cascade merge pipeline has run.** I'm guessing it's because branch updates from within a pipeline circumvents other triggers.

This is our YAML for the Sigrid pipeline:

```yaml
stages:
  - stage: Report
    jobs:
    - job: SigridCI
      pool: Default
      continueOnError: true
      condition: "eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')"
      steps:
      - powershell: "git clone https://github.com/Software-Improvement-Group/sigridci.git sigridci"
        displayName: Clone SigridCI from Github
      - powershell: "python ./sigridci/sigridci/sigridci.py --customer <our-customers-name> --system <our-project-name> --source . --targetquality $(RatingTarget) --exclude $(ExcludedFiles)"
        displayName: Run SIG script
        env:
          SIGRID_CI_TOKEN: $(SIGRID_CI_TOKEN)
        continueOnError: true
      - task: CopyFiles@2
        inputs:
          sourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/sigrid-ci-output'
          targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/sigrid-ci-output'
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        inputs:
          PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/sigrid-ci-output'
          ArtifactName: sigrid-ci-output
    - job: SigridPublish
      pool: Default
      continueOnError: true
      condition: "eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')"
      steps:
      - powershell: "git clone https://github.com/Software-Improvement-Group/sigridci.git sigridci"
        displayName: Clone SigridCI from Github
      - powershell: "python ./sigridci/sigridci/sigridci.py --customer <our-customers-name> --system <our-project-name> --source . --publishonly --exclude $(ExcludedFiles)"
        displayName: Run SIG script
        env:
          SIGRID_CI_TOKEN: $(SIGRID_CI_TOKEN)
        continueOnError: true
```

I've tried adding a overwriting trigger on the pipeline without success:

[image]

Is it possible to trigger the Sigrid pipeline when the cascade merge pipeline updates the `master` branch? Alternatively, can I trigger the Sigrid pipeline (from the `master` branch!) as a final step in the cascade merge pipeline?

Comment: It's most likely this line: `condition: "eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')"`. You'll want to add some additional conditions.

Comment: @DanielMann isn't that condition only related to the first job? If I run the pipeline manually and selects the `master` branch, it runs as expected. I.e. only the second job (SigridPublish) runs. The problem is that the pipeline doesn't even trigger, so I don't think these conditions are checked at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can have pipelines trigger other pipelines by configuring pipeline resource triggers.

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: triggeringPipeline # Name of the pipeline resource.
    source: triggeringPipeline-ci # The name of the pipeline referenced by this pipeline resource.
    project: ADOProject # Required only if the source pipeline is in another project
    trigger: true # Use this syntax to trigger the pipeline when any version of the source pipeline completes.
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops) is the Microsoft documentation on how to properly set up this type of trigger.

Comment: Thanks I think we tried something like this without luck, but will give it another go. In the documentation, however, it doesn't seem like I have control over which branch to run the **triggered** pipeline from. It seems to always run from the same branch as the **triggering** pipeline. (The pipelines are in the same repository)